# Links not working after partial reload

Tags: jquery, laravel-5

I am populating view through partials. At this point the links work fine because the page is reloaded. But, when add a new item through ajax then the link doesn't work. And also I have used `on` in jquery click function. This is weird because `on` is usually used in this kind of scenario.

So, what is the solution for this scenario?

I am using **Laravel 5.0.***

Answer (score 0):

try using this

```
 $( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
   $( ".log" ).text( "Triggered ajaxComplete handler." );
 });
```

or this

```
$(document).bind('ready ajaxComplete', function(){
  // Your code here
 })
```